# How do you change the width of columns in a Key in a lattice graph?

Tags: r, key, width, lattice

When I add a key to my xyplot (fore example:

```
key=list(space='top', columns=2,rows=2, text=list(c('A','B','C','D')),rectangles=list(col=c('black','green','red','blue'),size=2)
```

It creates columns that are separated by white space.

How do I control (i.e. shrink) this white space?

I've looked meticulously through the par.settings and have found nothing that works.

Comment: See `between.columns` under `key` in `?xyplot`.

Comment: Oy, Probably just looked right by it when I was viewing ?xyplot.
Thanks!

Comment: No problem. Heaven knows it's easy enough to miss details in that help file :=). Untangling the various options implied by `key=` and `auto.key=` and `simpleKey()` and `legend=` is no mean feat! And that's not even mentioning the additional options available via `trellis.par.set()` and `lattice.options()` and `grid::gpar()`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though trellis options are often numerous and difficult to read through, this question has an easy solution that was simply overlooked by the OP (me).  As @Josh O'Brien's comment above demonstrates, `between.columns` under `key` in `?xyplot` will take care of the white space between key columns.